# ftp shell mput file not match

Tags: shell, ftp

I use ftp shell script to upload data below:

```
find . -type d -exec ./recursive-ftp.sh {} \;
```

recursive-ftp.sh is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp_site="<skip>"
username="<skip>"
passwd="<skip>"
localDir="<skip>"
folder=$1
cd <skip>
pwd
ftp -in <<EOF
open $ftp_site
user $username $passwd
mput *
mkdir $folder
cd $folder
lcd $folder
mput *
close
bye
```

But I found the file size & md5 is different from the orignal file.
ftp use tcp,why are some files different?

Comment: When files are transferred by ftp with ASCII mode, newline characters in the file may be changed according to default newline charasters of source machine and destination machine. For example, when you transfer a file from Windows to Linux by FTP, newline character of Windows (CR+LF) will be changed to newline character of Linux (LF). In this case transferred file is smaller than original.

Comment: My Operating system is mac os, and remote machine is Windows, maybe Fumu you are right,but how can I fix it?

Comment: Use BINARY mode instead of ASCII mode. If you Add a 'binary'  command before 'mput *' comand , files are transferred by BINARY mode.